# Organizing Assemblies for Several WCF Services in same Domain

Tags: wcf, assemblies, bin

Well, the problem is how to organize assemblies for several *WCF* services hosted in the same domain, when the services might use different versions of the same referenced assemblies?

The thing is, that I have a series of *WCF* services which are currently hosted in the same domain, but the burden of updating one of these services is overwhelming due to the fact that I cannot be sure not to break other services when doing so. Therefore, it requires that I bring all other services up-to-date with the new version of assembly or assemblies which  I am going to publish.

Updating the service - in my case - would be do change one or more assemblies in the *bin* folder. The problem is that other services might need the same assemblies. I would like to have the possibility of defining subfolders with the name of the service, and in each of these folder have a *bin* subfolder, the *.svc* file and all other stuff related to the service. This way I could isolate the service on the same domain.

I have searched for a solution and I have found a blog post by *Scott Hanselman* about probing, but it seems to apply to *.NET 1.1*, *ASP.NET*...

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=4d0ef4fb-f8ae-4355-a658-3c0432c98dbe

Unfortunately, I cannot make it work for my scenario (*.NET 4.0*). Furthermore, I am not sure that this would scale the way I need. Even if I could make it work, then is it going to be seperate *AppDomains*, and if not would that be a problem? I need the complete isolation of the service, but still being hosted in the same domain.

Thanks, Jacob.

**Update**

Actually, I got a bit further. I tried to put the *[ServiceName].svc.cs* and the interface into its own project and compile it, and then change the *.svc* file slightly to reference the assembly just created as described by *Hanselman*. If I leave out the *Import* statement also mentioned in his post and doing the other bits aswell, then it actually works.

The only thing is if I have a list of paths, something like...

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="Tasks\bin;Products\bin"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

... then can I be sure that the assemblies used are from the right folder, and not resolved in the order they appear in the list? An example could be if the *ProductsService* uses the same assembly as *TaskService* but in a different version, then if the assembly is resolved in the order they appear in the *privatePath* string above then it would use the wrong assembly I guess? Then it is not completely isolated after all.

If I am right in this assumption, then perhaps strong-naming is the answer?

Thanks again, Jacob.

Comment: Can't you just create child applications? `http://myendpoint.mycompany.com/Tasks/TaskService.svc` and `http://myendpoint.mycompany.com/Products/ProductsService.svc`? Then they won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Thanks, John, and sorry for not explaining it good enough. What you are suggesting is what I am actually doing. One subfolder for each service, however, the assemblies still have to reside in the bin folder of the root. Perhaps what is confusing is that it is not only the assembly for the service, it is also my own libraries, e.g. MyCompany.Security.dll, MyCompany.Web.dll etc., and they can be referenced in the services in different versions. Thanks anyway, Jacob.

Comment: @Jacob: make one project per folder - each will be an IIS application, so each will have its own bin folder. They can still share common code.

Comment: Hi John. One VS project? Do you mean that I should put all my code for a single service in one DLL? If so that would not be an optimal solution since my code is well-organized in libraries, which is referenced. Or do you mean doing seperate virtual folder under the same virtual folder or something like that?

Comment: @Jacob: one project per service, and the projects can reference the libraries, which can remain well-organized.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help. I still haven't figured it out. I have tried to configure IIS6 to have a "Web Site" for each service (assume it is the same as "Application" for IIS7) that physically points at the sub-folder for the service and then add the bin directory and a web.config into this sub-folder, but still can't make it work. Can it be done at IIS6 at all? I see the  point in different "Applications" since it then loads DLLs in different AppDomains. Thanks, Jacob.

Comment: ... I might add that it seems to work as required on IIS7.

Comment: Finally, it now seems to work in IIS6 also. I will post the solution shortly. Thanks for your help, John. Best regards, Jacob.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is [Service Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx) rather than probing.

You have *clients* which need to use different versions of the same *service* over the network. This is a common issue and is addressed by **Service Versioning**. So they are not referencing DLLs, they connect to the service.

So you just create a new version, deploy to a new endpoint and get new clients using the new service.

Comment: Thanks, but it is in fact different services and not just different versions, examples could be a TaskService, a ProductService, an EmailService and so on, thanks anyway. Actually I think I got a bit further. See update in the original post in a few minuttes...